# How to disable password encoding in grails 3.x.x

Tags: grails, groovy, encoding, passwords

I am facing issue while creating/updating password in grails 3.x.x Application. Whenever i try to enter any special case lets say "@" it encodes only this special character in password field.
Password value is coming from request body.

```
Example:
Real password : abc@555
Auto Encoded password : abc%40555
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information.  The answer will depend on where the un-encoded values are coming from (reading from a file?, request parameters? body of a request?...) and what in particular is doing the encoding.

Comment: Looks like you're sending passwords as a request parameter in a GET request...  You shouldn't do this

Answer (score 1):

Grails by default uses a plugin that uses bcrypt algorithm to hash passwords for security.There are some configurable password hashing attributes. You can customize the password plugin with the grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm attribute.